# Customize laravel spatie cookie consent

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

In my laravel application, I'm trying to implement cookie policy notice using [Spatie cookie consent](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent)

Here, I am able to integrate the notice correctly, but I want to change the div content and the style according to my UI design.

I could do the customization by changing the vendor files as mentioned in the git repo.

But since changing vendor files are not a good practice, How can I customize my cookie bar and its's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent#customising-the-dialog-contents) command to publish the views:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\CookieConsent\CookieConsentServiceProvider" --tag="cookie-consent-config"
```

After that you'll have 2 blade files:

> resources/views/vendor/cookieConsent/dialogContents.blade.php
> resources/views/vendor/cookieConsent/index.blade.php

So just edit them as you want.

**For addition**: as you can see, there might be some stuff in that blades like this:

```
@include('cookieConsent::dialogContents')
  or
@include('cookieConsent::index')
```

This means that your views file names are **dialogContents.blade.php** and **index.blade.php**, which should be located graphically like this:

```
                             packageName::relative.path.with.dots
                 @include('cookieConsent::dialogContents')
"resources/views/vendor" + cookieConsent/ dialogContents .blade.php

                             packageName::relative.path.with.dots
                 @include('cookieConsent::index')
"resources/views/vendor" + cookieConsent/ index .blade.php
```

You can edit them, or you can create your own views anywhere you want in **resources/views/...** and use them, but for this case you should include them as with default laravel syntax (with dots) like this:

```
@include('folder.subfilder.view')
```

If you don't have published your views, the package will automatically read them from **vendor/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent/resources/views/...** by default.

Similarly, you can customize the translations if need, doing [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent#customising-the-dialog-texts):

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\CookieConsent\CookieConsentServiceProvider" --tag="cookie-consent-config"
```

or config file like [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent#installation):

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\CookieConsent\CookieConsentServiceProvider" --tag="cookie-consent-translations"
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: after your customization (views, translations, configs, etc), don't forget to refresh your caches

```
php artisan config:cache
# for Laravel 6 and high:
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: yes but this is about editing the vendor files, as per my understanding editing vendor files is not a good thing. That's why I wanted to know if there is any other way of doing this...

Comment: You're right about vendor files: you don't have to change anything in vendor, but it's about the root "vendor" folder, but not for "resources/views/vendor" folder. That new "vendor" folder name is just for convention. You easy can (and for need you must) change that files. Also if you want you can rename the name "vendor" or just replace that files into somwhere else, but in that case I've write how you should include them.

Comment: when you publishing some views, configs etc, it just copying the files from root vendor folder and paste them into your application tracking folders, so you can customize yhem as you want.  If you don't have anything published, laravel will read them appropriately from the root vendor folder